# How to just run simple commands like teleop between PC and Workstation

Tags: ros, teleop

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I set up the environment and it satisfies these requirements:
http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot/Tutorials/hydro/Network%20Configuration

What do I do to allow the basic commands like

```
roslaunch turtlebot_teleop keyboard_teleop.launch
```

to work from my Workstation.

Also, are version fo ROS backward compatible?
The turtlebot PC is running an older release, hydro, and I installed jade on my workstation.

-piet

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221109/how-to-just-run-simple-commands-like-teleop-between-pc-and-workstation/) by [piet](https://answers.ros.org/users/25115/piet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-11-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try setting the  `ROS_MASTER_URI` to the ip of your robot: `export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://<robot_ip>:11311/` without `<>`. Then you can try to run `rostopic list` and see if you get the topics from your turtlebot. If that works, start the launch file in that terminal.

In general you should use the same ROS version everywhere but if you only use standard messages and their definition did not change, it should still work. But do make sure you install the same ROS version eventually.

---

Originally posted by [Chrissi](https://answers.ros.org/users/15386/chrissi/) with karma: 1642 on 2015-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1